# InitializeComponent in C# doesn't exsist

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using .net 4 and I don't see  the InitializeComponent method. Is it there?

Here is my class file that i am using

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;  //must add reference
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;  //must add reference
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;


public class Client : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox inputTextBox;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox displayTextBox;

    private NetworkStream output;
    private BinaryWriter writer;
    private BinaryReader reader;

    private string message = "";
    private Thread readThread;


    private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

    //default constructor
    public Client()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        readThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunClient));
        readThread.Start();
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new Client());
    }

    protected void Client_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Environment.Exit(System.Environment.ExitCode);
    }


    //sends text the user typed to server
    protected void inputText_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                writer.Write("CLIENT>>>> " + inputTextBox.Text);

                displayTextBox.Text += "\r\nCLIENT>> " + inputTextBox.Text;

                inputTextBox.Clear();
            }


        }
        catch
        {
            displayTextBox.Text += "\nError writing object";
        }
    } //end method inputTextBox_KeyDown


    //connects to server and display server-generated text
    public void RunClient()
    {

        TcpClient client;

        //Instantiate TcpClient for sending data to server
        try
        {
            displayTextBox.Text += "Attempting connection...\r\n";

            //Step 1: create TcpClient and connect to server
            client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect("localhost", 5000);

            //Step 2: Get NetworkStream associated with TcpClient
            output = client.GetStream();

            //creates objects for writing and reading across streams
            writer = new BinaryWriter(output);
            reader = new BinaryReader(output);

            displayTextBox.Text += "\r\nGot I/O stream\r\n";

            inputTextBox.ReadOnly = false;

            //loop until server signals termination
            do
            {

                //Step 3: processing phase
                try
                {
                    //read message from the server
                    message = reader.ReadString();
                    displayTextBox.Text += "\r\n" + message;
                }

                //handle exception if error in reading server data
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    System.Environment.Exit(System.Environment.ExitCode);
                }


            } while (message != "SERVER>>> TERMINATE");

            displayTextBox.Text += "\r\nClosing connection.\r\n";

            //Step 4: close connection
            writer.Close();
            reader.Close();
            output.Close();
            client.Close();
            Application.Exit();

        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What type of project are you using (winforms, asp.net, wpf, etc)?

Comment: its a windows project. I added all the necessary references to the project.

Comment: Have you added any controls to the form?

Comment: When I tried typing it, in the autocomplete it doesn't show up.

Comment: @Steffan, Can you please show us the code-file?

Comment: @Steffan: why do you want `InitializeComponent`? What did you plan to do with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method InitializeComponent is not defined or abstracted by Control or any of its children (like Form); it is generated, 100% from scratch, by the designer. It is also private; you cannot call it from outside the control class. If you have not developed this Control class from the designer, you do not have an InitializeComponent method unless you create one yourself.

Comment: Also, doesn't the designer place the InitializeComponent method in a `partial` class now too? I haven't written a winforms app in some time, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Yes it does, but members in one partial declaration are still accessible from other parts; the partial keyword is just a compiler hint that multiple source files create one class, so any code that works when the class is in one file will work if it's split into partials.